# Timer to generate overflow every 4ms

Tags: timer, interrupt, avr

On atmega2560 (STK600 board), I am using Timer0 which is 8-bit timer. I want to generate an overflow every 4ms...how do I set the timer for 4ms? (the clock speed is 8MHz, I am aware of setting up a timer by diving (clock speed)/(prescaler) and when the counter resets, it generates an overflow interrupt. But not sure about setting for 4ms!

Secondly, once the timer overflows and generates an OVERFlOW interrupt, calculate 1 second..How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4ms won't be possible with the OVERFLOW interrupt:

F_CPU = 8,000,000hz

F_OVERFLOW = 1/0.004s = 250hz

CYCLES_PER_OVERFLOW = F_CPU / F_OVERFLOW = 32,000, i.e.: An overflow should occur each 32,000 CPU clock cycles

CYCLES_PER_TIMER_TICK = 32,000 / 256 = **125** = prescaler value

125 is not available as prescaler, but you can use 128 if that's close enough for your purpose (4.096ms).
If not, you can consider to use a timer compare interrupt instead of the overflow int. - Or change F_CPU...

Once you have your interrupt each 4ms, you can increment a global variable on each interrupt and each time the variable's value reaches 250, another second has passed and the variable can be re-set to 0 to count towards the next second.